# Flutter close Splash on api success

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a splash screen and i am running api on splash what i need to is when my API success then i need to disable api right now its on duration but i want to close when my API successfully run

My code

```
class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dosomestuff();
  }
  Future<List> dosomestuff() async {
    print('run');
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      'http://retailapi.airtechsolutions.pk/api/settings/user/2170',
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(res.body);
    print(map);
    print(map['Status']);
    if (int.parse(map['Status']) == 1) {
      print('aga chal');
      final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
      await storage.write(
          key: '_LocationID', value: map['LocationID'].toString());
      await storage.write(
          key: '_UserID', value: map['UserID'].toString());
      await storage.write(
          key: '_TaxPercentTaxPercent', value: map['TaxPercent']);
      await storage.write(
          key: '_DeliveryCharges', value: map['DeliveryCharges']);
      await storage.write(key: '_Currency', value: map['Currency']);

    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      splash: 'assets/icons/logo.png',
      nextScreen: SplashWelcomePage(),
      splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
      pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.fade,
      duration: 1000,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FutureBuilder and display splash screen when connection state is loading

```
FutureBuilder(
 future: dosomestuff(),
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)  {
     return SplashScreen()
   }
   //... return widget when success/error
 }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create bool

   bool _finishLoad = false;
2. Modify initState

   ```
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        dosomestuff().then((_) {
          setState((){
            _finishLoad = true
          }));
      }
   ```
3. Modify build

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   ```
    return _finishLoad ? AnimatedSplashScreen(
      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      splash: 'assets/icons/logo.png',
      nextScreen: SplashWelcomePage(),
      splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
      pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.fade,
      duration: 1000,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
    ) : Container();
   ```

   }